# How to access IntVar or StringVar or DoubleVar or BooleanVar from its master

Tags: python, tkinter

my code looks like this

```
root = Tk()
a = IntVar(root)
```

later in my code i cannot access 'a' but i can access 'root'
I tried

```
root.getvar('a')
root.children
root.client()
root.slaves()
root.getint(0)
```

and none of them is or contains 'a'

and I need value from 'a'
how can I get it

Comment: There is not enough code here to see what you are doing and to be able to judge what is wrong. Please provide more code. Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @BryanOakley 
Tk object  does not have 'get' method and I'm trying to get 'a' from 'root', not vice versa, so I can't use master parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get a tkinter variable given only the root window, or the master of a widget. At least, not without a lot of work. Tkinter simply doesn't keep track of these variables for you.

To gain access to the variable, you must do the same with it as you do with any other python variable or object: you need to make it global, or a class or instance variable, or you need to pass it to the function that needs access.

Comment: actually, tkinter does keep track of those variables. though it is unpractical. every variable has default name `'PY_VAR'` + integer. to retrieve it write `root.tk.globalgetvar(name)`. though you need variable's name, thus impracticality. another solution is to name variable like so `a = IntVar(name = 'my_name')` in which case it may not be so unpractical